# Loop through an excel range and fill text boxes from range

Tags: vba, excel, userform, ranged-loops

I'm currently working on a userform within excel. It currently pulls a list from a database and pastes this into excel then references that data to autofill in textboxes when you select someones name.

What I am having trouble with is I also want to autofill the access to certain systems a staff member will have. Basically the spreadsheet contains all staff within the company and the access they have to certain systems consisting of 2 cells (System and entitlement, columns K and L). I have defined the range I wish to work with but I am now stuck.

How do I get excel to loop through the range and "Copy and paste" the data from each cell (eg K2 and l2) into text boxes in the userform. So what I want to happen is select someones name and it will automatically pull through all their access details and autofill some textboxes with that access and entitlement.

Current code I have is as per below.
    Private Sub cboStaffNumber_Change()

```
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim rngNumber As Range
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngRangeStart As Long
Dim lngRangeEnd As Long
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim rngColumn As Range
Dim rngEntitlement As Range
Dim rngAccess As Range

Set rngNumber = Range("A2:A" & lngStaffDataLastRow)

'Fills in the Staff Name, OIA Template, Division, Job Title and WAP Code fields when a staff member is selected
    If bCboBool = False Then
        If Me.cboStaffNumber.ListIndex > 0 Then
            For Each rngCell In rngNumber.Cells
                If rngCell.Value = Val(cboStaffNumber.Value) Then
'                    lngRangeStart = rngCell.Row
                    bCboBool = True
                    Me.cboStaffName = rngCell.Offset(0, 1)
                    Me.txtOIATemplate = rngCell.Offset(0, 9)
                    Me.txtDivision = rngCell.Offset(0, 7)
                    Me.txtJobTitle = rngCell.Offset(0, 2)
                    Me.txtWAP = rngCell.Offset(0, 3)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next rngCell
        Else
            Me.cboStaffName.Value = ""
            Me.txtOIATemplate.Value = ""
            Me.txtDivision.Value = ""
            Me.txtJobTitle.Value = ""
            Me.txtWAP.Value = ""
        End If
    End If

For lngRow = 2 To lngLastRow
    If rngNumber.Cells(lngRow, 1).Value = Val(cboStaffNumber.Value) Then
        lngRangeStart = lngRow
        Exit For
    End If
Next lngRow

'    For lngRow = lngRangeStart To lngLastRow + 1
'        If rngNumber.Cells(lngRow, 1).Value <> Val(cboStaffNumber.Value) Then
'            lngRangeEnd = lngRow
'            Exit For
'        End If
'    Next lngRow
'
'    If lngRow <> 0 Then
'        lngRangeEnd = lngRangeEnd - 1
'    End If
'
'    For rngAccess = lngRangeStart To lngRangeEnd
'        Set rngCell = lngRangeStart.Cells(rngCell, 11)
'            For Each rngCell In rngAccess
'                Set txtAccess1 = rngCell
'                Exit For
'    Next rngAccess



    bCboBool = False




End Sub`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can the staff member appear multiple times in the data your getting the System and Access for each staff member from?

Comment: Yes, so the data will contain the same staff member information but different system and access information.
It might end up being 100+ lines of access, but also sometimes only 1-2 lines of access. Across those lines the staff information will remain the same but system and access will change. 
EG (System 1, Access 1) then next line with same staff information (System 1, Access 2). The system can also change as staff can have access to multiple systems. all I want to do is put each system plus access combination that the specific staff member has and autofill the text boxes of the userform

Answer (score 0):

The below should give you the basics to loop through and update a variable with the values of each System and Access cell for the staff member based on their staff number. You'll need to change the values in [] to the named values in your form. It also works off of the original range which you defined 'rngNumber'. I've not tested it, but at a glance it should work. Let me know how it goes.

```
strSystem = ""
strAccess = ""
For Each rngCell In rngNumber.Cells
     If rngCell.Value = Val(cboStaffNumber.Value) Then
          strSystem = strSystem & rngCell.Offset(0,10).value & ", "
          strAccess = strAccess & rngCell.Offset(0,11).value & ", "
     End If
Next rngCell
If len(strSystem) > 0 then
     strSystem = Left(strSystem, len(strSystem)-1)
End If
If len(strAccess) > 0 then
     strAccess = Left(strAccess , len(strAccess)-1)
End If
Me.[txtSystemBox] = strSystem 
Me.[txtAccessBox] = strAccess
```